# Query to select a record with highest value

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007

In Microsoft Access 2007, I have a table with following columns:

```
col1    mmonth yyear      col4   
a1  5      2013       Pete
a1  4      2013       John
a1  3      2013      Don
a2  7      2013      Elsa
a2  8      2012      Rick
a3  9      2009      Betty
a3  10     2001      Vera
a3  8      2013      Ronald
```

With a query, I want to reach the records with the highest number in mmonth and yyear as follows:

```
col1    mmonth yyear      col4   
a1  5      2013       Pete
a2  7      2013      Elsa
a3  8      2013      Ronald
```

Comment: i'm tried apply this code on the table but the table retrieved the error values in yyear column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RANK()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY yyear DESC, mmonth DESC) AS rk
        FROM   some_table) t
WHERE  t.rk <= <number of records you want>
```

Comment: what do you mean <number of records you want>                         can you give me value as above example

Comment: If you want the top five records, replace it with 5. If you want the top seven, replace it with 7, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`this should do it`

```
with cte as (

select col4,col1,max(month) as mm,max(year) as yy,RANK() over(order by year desc,month desc) as rn from table
group by col1,year,month,col4

)

select col1,yy,mm,col4 from cte where rn <4
```

Comment: giving you `top 3` results !!